# How to cook tofu without burning?

Tags: vegetarian, frying-pan, tofu

I've been trying to eat tofu lately (not using much oil to cook it) and I don't mind it, my only problem is that I can't seem to cook it without burning the pan and setting the smoke alarms off (twice!!). The actual tofu turns out ok but the pan comes out pretty blackened and hard to clean.

Thanks.

Comment: How exactly are you cooking your tofu for this to happen?

Comment: Baking tofu is pretty easy.

Comment: So is putting it in a soup

Comment: It doesn't sound like the tofu is the thing burning, please outline your actual steps and quantities.

Comment: Are you trying to *render* the tofu in the pan? That won't work :)

Answer (score 3):

If it is firm tofu: Don't use not much oil to cook it. If you want to get by with using very little oil, bake it - but cover it in either SOME oil or marinade.

For frying, shallow or deep frying (warning: press the water out well before deep frying!) simply yields better results than sauteeing, unless the tofu is crumbled or cut very finely (which gives more of a minced meat texture).

If it is soft tofu, consider boiling it in a sauce (like in mapo dofu), or even serving it steamed/raw with a sauce (check if you variety is safe to consume raw) as is not infrequently done as a japanese style desert.

If you are looking for recipes that work well with firm tofu, check indian recipes that involve paneer cheese - most of them can be easily adapted to make great tofu dishes.